# Why is expanding a parameter pack into an array not a constant expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, constexpr

Yes, I can use `std::initializer_list`. Doesn't matter for the purposes of this question.

Question is, why is unpacking a parameter pack not a constant expression, even though I am passing only integer literals to the constructor?

```
template<typename T>
class ilist
{
private:
    const T* beg;
    const T* end;

public:
    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr ilist(Args&&... args) noexcept
    {
        // constexpr variable 'arr' must be initialized by a constant expression
        constexpr T arr[sizeof...(args)] = { args... };
        beg = arr;
        end = arr + sizeof...(args);
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr ilist<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
}
```

Comment: Not everything that always produces the same result is a :"constant expression" as defined by the standard.

Comment: shouldn't the body of a constexpr constructor be empty ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Not neccessarily. As far as I know, the body of a constexpr function has to satisfy the constrains of a constexpr function body. Doesn't really matter in this case, because the question is more about why the array initialization from the parameter pack is not allowed to be constexpr.

Comment: you're assigning the address of the local object arr to the constexpr member pointer beg. This is not allowed in a constant expression (and it's not a good idea in any case).